# MVC4 mobile to dynamically use _Layout.cshtml instead of _Layout.Phone.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, layout, asp.net-mvc-4, overriding

Please be gentle with me, this is my first question on StackOverflow following many years of lurking.

I have an MVC4 site already up and running. I am adding mobile support to the site which is all going well using the standard MVC functionality:

**I need some code to allow the framework to use Layout.cshtml if there is no ".Phone" version of the view**

## Example 1

I have the following files:

```
Views/Home/HasBoth.cshtml
Views/Home/HasBoth.Phone.cshtml

Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml
Views/Shared/Layout.Phone.cshtml
```

### Called with Desktop

1. Call /Home/HasBoth
2. Framework picks up is **not** mobile device
3. Framework calls Layout.cshtml
4. Framework calls HasBoth.cshtml

This is great.

### Called with Mobile

1. Call /Home/HasBoth
2. Framework picks up **is** mobile device
3. Framework calls Layout.Phone.cshtml
4. Framework calls HasBoth.Phone.cshtml

Again, this is also great.

## Example 2

I have the following files:

```
Views/Home/HasNoPhone.cshtml

Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml
Views/Shared/Layout.Phone.cshtml
```

Note: there is no Views/Home/HasNoPhone.Phone.cshtml

### Called with Desktop

1. Call /Home/HasNoPhone
2. Framework picks up is **not** mobile device
3. Framework calls Layout.cshtml
4. Framework calls HasNoPhone.cshtml

This is great.

### Called with Mobile

1. Call /Home/HasNoPhone
2. Framework picks up **is** mobile device
3. **Code here to work out there is no HasNoPhone.Phone.cshtml view**
4. Framework calls **Layout.cshtml**
5. Framework calls **HasNoPhone.cshtml**

The above is what I want to acheive.

## EDIT

## Solution used

Thanks to Zoka, I am now using the following for anyone else who wishes to do something similar:

Helper method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Looks to see if the view the exists.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="viewName">The view name.</param>
/// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param>
/// <returns>True if the view exists.</returns>
public static bool ViewExists(string viewName, ControllerContext controllerContext)
{
  ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, null);
  return result.View != null;
}
```

_ViewStart.cshtml :

```
@{                                                                                                             
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";                                                                    

  // If a mobile viewing and no <view>.Phone.cshtml file is found set the override to desktop.                 
  // This will ensure _Layout.Phone.cshtml and yyy.Phone.cshtml partials are not called.                       
  string action = (string)ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue;                    
  string controller = (string)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];                                      
  string viewPhoneName = "~/Views/" + controller + "/" + action + ".Phone.cshtml";                             
  if (ViewContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice &&                                         
    MvcHelperAbove.ViewExists(viewPhoneName, ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext) == false) 
  {                                                                                                            
    ViewContext.HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Desktop);                                     
  }                                                                                                            
}
```

_Layout.Phone.cshtml

```
...
@* Below is essential to allow css to work when going from Mobile to Desktop *@
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
  });
</script>
...
```

Thanks again all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you need to find out if some view exists. I use such function placed in any class accessible from views:

```
public static bool ViewExists(string _name, ControllerContext _controller_context)
{
    ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(_controller_context, _name, null);
    return (result.View != null);
}
```

Then put this into _ViewStart.cshtml:

```
string action = (string)ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue;
string controller = (string)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
var viewPhoneName = "~/Views/" + controller + "/" + action + ".Phone.cshtml";
if (YourNamespaceAndClassForAboveHelper.ViewExists(viewPhoneName, ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext)) {
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.Phone.cshtml"
} else {
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml"
}
```

And finally in Layout.cshml (respectively in Layout.Phone.cshtml), instead of call to `RenderBody`

```
string action = (string)ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue;
string controller = (string)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
@RenderPage("~/Views/" + controller + "/" + action + ".cshtml"); @* .Phone.cshtml in Layout.Phone.cshtml *@
```

Comment: Thanks Zoka, have edited the solution and used bits of yours above. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use an existing jquery mobile package:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx

Edit:
Maybe you could use a page installer and register your pages in a container. That way your controller can ask your container which view he should return.

[Creating WindsorViewPageActivator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433485/creating-windsorviewpageactivator)

Comment: Thanks Ian. This is what I am already using and the problem manifests in the way I have mentioned. Zoka's answer is close, will be having a play with that.

Comment: Sorry for my previous answer, but maybe you could use a page installer and register your pages in a container. That way your controller can ask your container which view he should return.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433485/creating-windsorviewpageactivator